# Strange MOTD on my Linux Box

Tags: linux

I'm setting up new Linux box, CentOS 4.9

> LSB Version:
>   :core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-ia32:graphics-3.0-noarch
>   Distributor ID: CentOS Description:
>   CentOS release 4.9 (Final) Release:
>   4.9 Codename: Final

When I login to personnel account via SSH, it shows following welcome message.

```
Last login: Sun Apr 17 21:56:53 2011 from xx.xx.xx.xx

[sh]  w.e.l.c.o.m.e
[sh]  To The Virtual Reality
[sh]  Enjoy and behave !
```

Is my Linux box hacked?
Should I have to reinstall CentOS?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the [signature of some guy named hexabyte in a hacker forum](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Nlr3PbqPqxcJ:www.ocean-leecher.net/forum/thread-9927.html%20%5Bsh%5D%20w.e.l.c.o.m.e%20%5Bsh%5D%20To%20The%20Virtual%20Reality%20%5Bsh%5D%20Enjoy%20and%20behave%20!&cd=5&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=at&source=www.google.at).

[image]

So, basically, I'd say your box is hacked or at least not an official version. Do a clean reinstall as soon as possible and make sure you download the **latest official version**!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced that there *was* a Centos 2.4.

I suggest you hire an operations engineer straight away. Consider all your data compromised and change all passwords (after you take the compromised system offline permanently). Restore backups with care.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what did you install to be honest, since this doesn't really sound like CentOS (whatever version it might be.)

Grab the *offical* ISO (and *latest*) from the official site: https://www.centos.org/
And do a clean install.

(If you really happened to install such an old release, yes it's really easy to hack it since if a Linux release goes outdate, it won't get security updates. That means, the attacker just have to get the version information of the services you run and find exploits for them.)